# How to make url from a string in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Does a Laravel has an included function to convert a string to an url? Or should I use some standart PHP libraries? But with standard library there is a problem with duplicating url... So there should be a script for every model..?

Example:

```
'Apple Cake'=>'apple-cake'
```

Comment: @MartinBean I have added an example. String in my case is some kind of title of an article for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you’re wanting to convert a title-case word to a URL-friendly string, then you can use the `Str::slug()` method:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slug = Str::slug('Apple Cake'); // apple-cake
```

Comment: This function is not included in "standard" Laravel anymore. You can either include the package "laravel/helpers" or use `Str::slug('Apple Cake');`

Comment: @Arangor Indeed, the helper function’s been removed in the near-four years since I wrote this answer. I’ve updated it with a version that will working in newer (as well as older) versions of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I also have found https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable slug maker for Laravel, if someone will have the same problem